# Simplified the cube root of the complex number

Tags: complex-numbers, radicals

I have simplified this cube root:

$$ \sqrt[3]{1+i}=\sqrt[6]{2}\bigl(\frac{\sqrt{6} + \sqrt{2}}{4} +{\frac{\sqrt{6} - \sqrt{2}}{4} }i\bigr)$$
which is simplified algebraic expression form.

Now, I was wondering if you can simplify this cube root in different simplified form ?

Like this :
$$ \sqrt[3]{1+i \sqrt{3}} =A + Bi \space\space\space\space\space?$$

Where $A$ and $B$ are constant numbers.

Or any simplified algebraic expression form?
Other than non-algebraic form like these:
$$ \cos(\theta) +i \sin(\theta) $$ or $$ e^{i \theta} $$

Comment: You can try and read up on the De Moivre Formula and the polar form of a complex number . From there you can try and simplify the expressions of $\cos(\frac{\pi}{9})$ and $\sin(\frac{\pi}{9})$

Comment: Steps to calculate $$(x + iy)^{1/3} ~: ~x,y \in \Bbb{R}, ~(x,y) \neq (0,0)$$ [1] Set $~\displaystyle r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}.~$ [2] Determine $\theta$ as the unique value in $-\pi < \theta \leq \pi$ such that $$\cos(\theta) = \frac{x}{r}, ~\sin(\theta) = \frac{y}{r}.$$  Then, the $3$ cube roots are given by $$r^{1/3} \times e^{i(2k\pi + \theta)/3} ~: ~k \in \{0,1,2\}.$$  As indicated by the comment of @Mr.GandalfSauron, this is a direct consequence of De Moivre's formula.

Comment: @user2661923 . Why not post it as an answer? It's such a good explanation.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Good question.  A year ago, I would have posted this as a hint-answer, leaving the OP (i.e. original poster) to work out the specific details, with respect to his posted problem.  However, my recent experiences with the MathSE *answer-police* have been distasteful, and (in this case) I do regard it as reasonable to construe the OP's posting as defective.  ...see next comment

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron So, until the OP improves the quality of his posting, with respect to [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236), for example, I prefer to steer clear of controversy.

Comment: Correct man, recently I have seen perfectly reasonable posts being deemed as low quality and earning downvotes .